# black screen delay after splash screen on iOS builds (Unity3d)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I thought it had something to do with the scene loading time, but I started a new project, built it and there is still a black screen after the splash, it's not bothering so much when you leave the original unity splash screen or use your own black splash screen, but in my project the splash screen is white, and the loading/logo scene following it is also with a white background, so it's kind of annoying to have white-black-white sequence, looks very buggy and unprofessional.

I think it has something to do with the loading indicator, when I change it to on, I get a black screen with the indicator, when it's off, just a black screen is showing.

I saw an early fix for unity 3.5, but the AppController.mm file does not exist in unity 4.5, I think they changed it to SplashScreen.mm, and I don't know how to modify so if anyone who familiar with those scripts can help me I'll appreciate it.

[unity 3.5 fix](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/black-screen-when-loading-on-ipad.143480/)

I used ipod 4 with ios 5.1.1 for testing.

Comment: downgrading unity to 4.3.4 fixed it

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this problem (other than downgrading to 4.3.4) is to delete the Launch image set generated by unity in the image.xcassets and replace it by your own new one. Make sure you name it LaunchImage and you add in it every resolution/orientation supported by your application.